# After adding position relative, the whole site shifts down

Tags: html, css

[image: Before loading the jquery for the fadeIn number img]

[image: After loading thr jquery for FadeIn number img]

After I loaded the number image which contains some jquery, the whole site shifted down.

Could it be due to the `position:relative` I am using ? Ignore the `2px border` I inserted for certain elements. I wanted to check the area that element encompasses.

Note:

The large image of food is related to the image slider - coin-slider.

The footer isn't shown in the screenshot I took.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

    <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
            <title> Foodstant Delivery </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="testCSS.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="coin-slider/coin-slider-styles.css"  />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script src="jqfloat/jqfloat.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="coin-slider/coin-slider.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#coin-slider').coinslider({ width:900, navigation: true, delay: 3000, hoverPause: true, effect: 'random' });

                $('#numb1').hide().delay(800).fadeIn('normal');

            });
        </script>

    </head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="numb1">    
                <img src="images/number4.png" />
            </div> 

        <figure id="logo"> 
            <img src="images/logo23.png" alt="Foodstant Delivery logo" width="" height="" />
        </figure>   

        <figure id="abtex">
            <img src="images/abtext126.png" />
        </figure>   

        <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li class="OP" id="OPM1"><img src="images/order.png"   /><a  href="Orders.html">Orders</a></li>
                <li class="OP" id="OPM"><img src="images/menupic3.png" /><a  href="Menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="OP"><img src="images/contact.png"  /><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="OP"><img src="images/Pen.png"  /><a href="AboutUs.html" target="_blank">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="OP"><img src="images/pin.png"   /><a  href="Jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>

            <div id='coin-slider'>

                     <img src='images/slideshow1x.png' />
                            <span>
                                Description for img01
                            </span>



                     <img src='images/slideshow2x.jpg' />
                            <span>
                                Description for img01
                            </span>



                     <img src='images/slideshow3x.jpg' />
                            <span>
                                Description for img01
                            </span>



                     <img src='images/slideshow4x.jpg' />
                            <span>
                                Description for img01
                            </span>

</div>
        <footer>
            <figure id="footerBg">
                <img src="images/BG_F_S3.png" alt="Footer Background" width="" height="" />

            </figure>   

        <div id="ftex"> 
            <ul>

                <li> © 2012 Foodstant Delivery  </li>

                 <li><a href="Sitemap.html">Sitemap</a> </li>

                <li id="ss">Search Site </li>
            </ul>   



        </div>  

        </footer> 

</div>

</body>


</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_LITHOSPRO-REGULAR';
    src: url('fonts/LITHOSPRO-REGULAR.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/LITHOSPRO-REGULAR.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/LITHOSPRO-REGULAR.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/LITHOSPRO-REGULAR.svg') format('svg');
}

body {
    background-image: url('images/BG-W1.png');
}
#container{
    max-width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 0 auto;
    height: 790px;
    /*border: 2px solid blue;*/
#logo {
    float:left;

}

#abtex {
    float: left;
    border:2px solid blue;
}

#navbar {
    background: rgb(246,248,249); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%, rgba(229,235,238,1) 46%, rgba(215,222,227,1) 65%, rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(246,248,249,1)), color-stop(46%,rgba(229,235,238,1)), color-stop(65%,rgba(215,222,227,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(245,247,249,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 46%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 65%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 46%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 65%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 46%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 65%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(246,248,249,1) 0%,rgba(229,235,238,1) 46%,rgba(215,222,227,1) 65%,rgba(245,247,249,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f8f9', endColorstr='#f5f7f9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;

    box-shadow: -3px -5px 10px  #888888;

    position: relative;
    top:-50px;
    clear:left;
    font-size: 26px;

    font-family: 'Conv_LITHOSPRO-REGULAR';
}

#navbar ul {
    list-style-position:inside;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}


#navbar ul li {     
        display: inline;
        padding:0 20px 0px 0px; 
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        list-style-type:disc;
    }

#navbar ul li.OP {
        /*list-style-image:url('images/order.png'); */
        padding-left: 20px;

}   

#navbar ul li.OP img {
    vertical-align: middle; 
}

li a:link {
  color: #EF174A;
  }

li a:visited {
  color: #BF4100;
  }

li a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color:#D2D2D2;
  border-radius: 10px; 
  }

li a:active {
  color: #918FBC;
  } 

li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}  

#navbar ul li.OP a {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#footerBg {
    position: relative;
    bottom:-63px;
    left:-50px;
}

#footerBg img {
    display: block;
}

#footertex {
    position: relative;
    top:-80px;

    /*border:2px solid black;*/

}

#ftex {
    position: relative;

}
#ftex ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    /*border:2px solid yellow;*/
    width:1200px;

}

#ftex ul li {
    display:inline;
    padding-right: 170px; 
    font-family: 'Conv_LITHOSPRO-REGULAR';
    font-size: 20px;
    /*border:2px solid red;*/
    color:#ffbf81;
}

#ftex li a:link {
  color: #ffbf81;
  border-bottom:4px solid #ffbf81;
  }

#ftex li a:visited {
  color: #ffbf81;
  border-bottom:4px solid #ffbf81;
  }

#ftex li a:hover {
  color: #ffbf81;
  background:none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom:4px solid #ffbf81;
  }

#ftex li a:active {
  color: #ffbf81;
  border-bottom:4px solid #ffbf81;
  } 

#ftex ul li#ss {
    border-bottom:4px solid #ffbf81;
    padding-right:5px;

}

#numb1 {
    position: relative;
    /*border:10px solid red;*/
    top:100px;
    border:2px solid red;

    right:-750px;
    /*z-index: 100;*/
    /*background:url(images/number2.png); */
}
```

Comment: Without looking over the whole thing...isn't '*' on this line `*$('#numb1').hide().delay(800).fadeIn('normal');` causing you trouble?

Comment: what about the double << ? in #numb1

Comment: @PeterPajchl , Removed it. The problem still persists.

Comment: @stetro, Deleted the extra < .

Comment: Try changing the `#numb1` to `position:absolute`

Comment: My original position setting is absolute. But it will overlap the text on its right at different screen resolutions. Thus, I switched back to relative, and this myserious gap at the top happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not the jQuery that is causing the site to shift down, but your `numb1` `div`.

The `div` elements takes up space on the page. Since by default `div` has `display: block`, it takes up a whole "line" area at the top of the page, where you've put it. Setting `position: relative` allows you the change the position of `numb1`, but it **still takes up the same space at its original position on the page** (the same spot as before).

One way of rectifying this is to use `position: absolute`, which will remove `numb1` from the flow of the document.

**Edit:**

Judging from your comments, I'm guessing you want to position the number relative to your logo and other figures without having the overlapping-on-different-screen-resolutions issue. One way of going about this is to put all your figures at the top of the page (including `numb1`) in a single `div` with `position: relative`. You can then give `numb1` `position: absolute`. This will allow you to position `numb1` **relative to the containing `div`**. Since you only have figures in the `div`, this will essentially allow you to position `numb1` relative to your figures.

Comment: THIS makes sense to me also +1

Comment: Many thanks. Your solution worked. It is now relative to the `container div` . On a sidenote, the chick logo img and footer img goes missing when I load it in IE9, are there any reasons why ?

Comment: ^ Solved the issue. Empty `widths` and `heights` apparently doesn't work well with IE.